# How can I check email relay is working or not?

Tags: administration, email-relay

In SFDC org (Environment hub - Partner Developer Edition)

whenever I send email from salesforce, I got the copy of that email in send Email folder on my email server. At this time [Email Relay](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=email_relay.htm&type=5) is not enabled.

Now if I enabled Email Relay, how do I know it is configured properly and it is in working state ?

How can I check, emails are going to my own mail servers ?

Comment: did you refer this https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_email_relay_considerations.htm&type=5

Answer (score 1):

To see that your email relay is working, send a message from Salesforce and in the recipient's inbox, select the message and display the headers.  For example, using gmail, you would use the "Show Original" context menu command

You can see the chain of email servers involved in sending the message by looking for the `Received: ...` entries. An email relay properly configured will have lines that look like this (Here, GSuite is the email relay)

```
Received: from smtp02-ph2-sp1.mta.salesforce.com (smtp02-ph2-sp1.mta.salesforce.com. [13.110.6.225])
 /*the email relay server ==> */ by smtp-relay.gmail.com with ESMTPS id f2sm207794pjs.0.2020.11.02.14.49.41
        for <cropredy@example.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Mon, 02 Nov 2020 14:49:42 -0800 (PST)
 /* NOTE! */   X-Relaying-Domain: example.com
Return-Path: <cropredy@example.com>
Authentication-Results: mx3-ph2-sp1.mta.salesforce.com x-tls.subject="/C=US/ST=California/L=San Francisco/O=salesforce.com, inc./OU=0:app;1:ph2;2:ph2-sp1;3:cs43;4:prod/CN=cs43-app2-3-ph2.ops.sfdc.net"; auth=pass (cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384)
```

### Common errors

- You forgot to configure and activate a Sender Domain (even if simply `*`) in the [Email Relay's Domain Filters](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_email_relay_overview.htm&type=5).
- You didn't whitelist the [Salesforce IP ranges](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000321501&type=1&mode=1) in your Mail Server